# Header in Yii2 syntax

Tags: yii2, http-headers, yii2-advanced-app

I can not alter on Yii2 syntax:

```
header("Refresh: 60; url={$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
```

The code below does not work:

```
$headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
$headers->set("Refresh: 60", "url={$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header name is `Refresh`, the rest is the value. So you should use:

```
$headers->set("Refresh", "60; url={$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
```